# How to change MapView.Marker "SIZE" without using image?

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I'm using react-native-maps to show a lot of pins. I know I can change the pin colors using the `pinColor` props. But is it possible to change the Marker pin size?

I've read all around, but all I could find was to change size of Image. Which basically means to use Image to replace the pins, which I don't want to do, because I had some previous trial with it, and sometimes the pin's sharp end, doesn't actually stick to the correct coordinate because of the image having some extra transparent margin at the bottom or top of the image, or the center of the image isn't exactly at the point of the pin horizontally.

And fixing all those things might take some extra time. So, I'm asking around whether it is possible to use MapView.Marker (the default marker shipped with the library from GoogleMaps) and just adjust the size with some props?

```
<MapView initialRegion={{
    latitude: this.props.defaultLatitude,
    longitude: this.props.defaultLongitude,
    latitudeDelta: this.props.defaultLatDelta,
    longitudeDelta: this.props.defaultLongDelta,
}}
    <Marker 
        coordinate={{
            latitude: this.props.defaultLatitude,
            longitude: this.props.defaultLongitude,
        }}
        pinColor="red"
        size={15} />
    <Marker 
        coordinate={{
            latitude: this.props.secondLat,
            longitude: this.props.secondLong,
        }}
        pinColor="green"
        size={20} /> {/* Is it possible to add a props like this? */}
</MapView>
```

I wanted a MapView with the 2 marker, having different sizes and different color, without using Image as the Icon, but just the default Pin from Google.

Is that possible?

Comment: did you find any solution for this @jakk ?